# Matter.js Collision Not Detecting

Tags: javascript, collision, matter.js

I'm trying to practice using matter.js to create top down levels Bomberman style.

Right now I want to get my circle, which is controlled by arrow keys to move and bump into static squares but it is just going through them. Did I set it up incorrectly? I have been coding for three months, so I might be quite slow sorry!

```
var Engine = Matter.Engine,
    World = Matter.World,
    Bodies = Matter.Bodies;

var engine = Engine.create();
var world = engine.world;

var player;
var rocks = [];
var cols = 7;
var rows = 7;

function setup() {
    createCanvas(750, 750);
    Engine.run(engine);

    player = new Player(300, 300, 25);

    var spacing = width / cols;
    for (var j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
        for (var i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
            var r = new Rocks(i * spacing, j * spacing);
            rocks.push(r);
        }
    }
}

function draw() {
    background(51);
    Engine.update(engine);
    for (var i = 0; i < rocks.length; i++) {
        rocks[i].show();
    }
    player.show();
    player.move();
}

function Player(x, y, r) {
    this.body = Bodies.circle(x, y, r);
    this.r = r;
    World.add(world, this.body);

    this.show = function () {
        ellipse(x, y, this.r * 2);
    }

    this.move = function () {
        if (keyIsDown(RIGHT_ARROW))
            x += 10;
        if (keyIsDown(LEFT_ARROW))
            x -= 10;
        if (keyIsDown(UP_ARROW))
            y -= 10;
        if (keyIsDown(DOWN_ARROW))
            y += 10;
        x = constrain(x, this.r, height - this.r);
        y = constrain(y, this.r, width - this.r);
    }
}

function Rocks(x, y, w, h, options) {
    var options = {
        isStatic: true
    }
    this.body = Bodies.rectangle(x, y, h, w, options);
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
    this.size = player.r * 2;
    World.add(world, this.body);

    this.show = function () {
        rect(x, y, this.size, this.size);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that you player is not drawn in the same position that the physics engine thinks its at.

in your Player function after the initialization of x and y the rest all need to be `this.body.position.x` and `this.body.position.y`.  Otherwise you're changing where the picture is drawn at but not where the player actually is.

I'm not entirely sure what all you want me to point out besides that but also I think you want to disable gravity with `engine.world.gravity.y = 0` and I was trying to fix the constrain function because as I tested it it wasn't working, I wasn't able to fix it but I'd recommend just making static boundary objects for the walls and just don't draw them.

Also matter.js processes the locations of objects from their centers.  When drawing the objects you either have to take that into consideration or switch the mode to `ellipseMode(CENTER);`, 'rectMode(CENTER);` .. etc.

I hope this helps